# Passing a php variable in a form to another page

Tags: php, html

I want to pass a php variable in my form to another page which does the database connection of that form. but i am unable to pass the variable. The other data in the form is sent through post method. How can I send the variable and receive it from other page.

I want to pass `$branch_id` in the below code to `create_centre_connect.php` page. The echo part is doing ok.

Can anybody help me?

```
<form id="f_c_centre" action="create_centre_connect.php?" method="post">Branch Name
  <?php echo "". "".$create_centre1. ""; ?>
  <?php global $branch_id; $branch_id=&$create_centre; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: You should show some of the code that you are using so we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: echo the field value into a hidden form element. That will be sent along with your post and you can then get it from $_POST

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting a variable (unless it is a special case, like a session variable) will set it only for that execution of that program.

If you want to pass data using a form, then put that data in a form control. A hidden input will do in this case.

```
<input 
    type="hidden"
    name="branch_id"
    value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($branch_id); ?>"
>
```

Comment: this works. thank you very much. hope this htmlspecialchars is important. I have no idea of it. any way my problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

just make an input that holds the value. You can't do it directly as the client is in between, so you can't force it to be the same that way, but still.

```
<form id="f_c_centre" action="create_centre_connect.php?" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $branch_id ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $your_check_hash ?>" />
</form>
```

You should add hashed value with a salt only you know, if you want be able to check if someone tampered with the id. So calc a hash based on the id and your secret, send only the hash and the id, and verify the hash in the receiving code.

Comment: This won't work I think - should be value="<?php echo $branch_id;?>"

Comment: @MarcelBalzer -  That runs the risk of making the page vulnerable to XSS. The data needs to be escaped.

Comment: Maybe..but so it's not working at all.

Comment: well, you are both right. and yes, those things need to be taken care of indeed, but it's more about how to get the data from a to b then a complete piece of code.

Comment: @Quentin I would've done escaping earlier when you retrieve that id, not here in the view.

Comment: @Nanne — Escaping is best done just before insertion. Getting it at the time of retrieval means you have to know where it is going to end up at the time of retrieval, and means you can't manipulate it (unless you leave escaping until after manipulation). It's far too easy to miss an escape routine when they are scattered throughout the codebase.

Comment: It depends on how your code is structured, if you have retrieved your data expecially for this view, I dont' see why you wouldn't, but its besides the point: the example code and this question is about how to sent. There is also a submit-method missing. And a `<html>` for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you want to pass through form should through a form elements. In your case, you need some hidden fields if you don't want you information to show on a web page. but be aware of any sensitive data should not be passed through form hidden fields because it's visible when view page source.

```
<form id="f_c_centre" action="create_centre_connect.php" method="post">
  <input type='hidden' name='create_centre1' value='<?php echo "$create_centre1"; ?>'>
  <input type='hidden' name='branch_id' value='<?php echo "$create_centre"; ?>'>
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Sumbit'>
</form>
```

in create_centre_connect.php page, you can user $_POST to get whatever value you passed.

Answer (score -1):

Use cURL to post your variables. Lets pretend that you have two inputs in your form which are username and password and you want to send then to abc.php

Try something like this,

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://testcURL/abc.php'
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        "username" => $_POST['username'],
        "password" => $_POST['password']
    )
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
$resp;
} ?>
```

And echo your posts on abc.php using `print_r($_POST);` and you can keep these codes in your same file and set action="SAMEFIEL" in your form.